# Is there a graphic tool to add new url schemes like XX://?

Tags: browser, mime-types, freedesktop, url

I would like to add a few url scheme, e.g `magnet://`, and add a simple mimetype for it.
So that I would be able to handle these links within my browser.

Is there any graphic tool I could utilize ?

Comment: Not sure if I get this right... you would like to register a default handler for a certain protocol in your browser ? i.e. when you click on e.g. a `magnet://` link, your browser would launch a certain app to open that particular url scheme ?

Comment: @don_crissti yes, and those protocols are not registered like ed2k://

Comment: I guess it's specific to each browser. For Firefox/Chromium registering the default handler is just a formality, _as long as the default application registers that mime type_. E.g. if I install `trasmission-gtk` the content of `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` will be updated with `x-scheme-handler/magnet=transmission-gtk.desktop;` specifically because transmission-gtk.desktop contains this line: `MimeType=application/x-bittorrent;x-scheme-handler/magnet;`. Then Firefox would ask if I want to open the magnet link with `transmission` and so would do Chromium (the latter uses `xdg-open`).

Comment: In Firefox it is possible to register the default handler for a specific protocol without having a system-wide-registered application for that url scheme. This is done through `about:config` > right-click anywhere in the grid, choose New > Boolean > Name: `network.protocol-handler.expose.magnet` > Value > false. Next time you click on a `magnet://` link Firefox will open the "Launch Application" dialog and you can even associate a CLI app. I don't know if that is even possible in Chromium.